Jest Fails to Mock Axios: ES6 Modules Not Transpiling with Babel Config (React + Redux)
I’m encountering an issue where Jest is failing to mock Axios properly in my React + Redux project. I’m using Babel to transpile ES6 modules, but it seems like Axios isn’t being transformed as expected, causing my Jest tests to break.
Setup:
React version: 18.2.0
Axios version: 1.6.8
Jest config: Using babel-jest for transforming files and mocking CSS/SCSS with identity-obj-proxy.
Includes @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react for transpiling modern JavaScript and JSX.
Using the @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs to handle ES6 module transformation.
ignore array set to transform node_modules but include Axios.
Here is an example of my babel config: ignore: [/node_modules/(?!axios)/],
and my Jest config: transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!(axios|other-module)/)"]
Tests fail with errors related to ES6 modules not being transformed, indicating that Axios is still being ignored during transpilation.
I've tried clearing the cache and reinstalling the node_modules and package-lock.json but to no avail.
Axios should be transpiled correctly in my Jest tests, allowing proper mocking and passing tests.
